# Intellisense -> Toggle Completion Mode (Grayed out)

Tags: c#, autocomplete, intellisense, code-completion

What are my options? 
I arleady made a topic before asking how to enable Intellisense in Visual C# 2010 Express

I reinstalled Visual C# 2010 Express twice now without any results.
I downloaded QuickSharp fresh install same issue no intellisense.
Maybe something wrong with my computer? Windows XP

I created a new Windows Forms Application here called it test.. and just clicked on Form to get Form_load code and typed System. (dot) (nothing pops out!)

I have reset the settings, this did absolutely nothing.

[image: grayed out]